# MDX: Member_Key returns 0 despite valid keys being available

Tags: mdx

I create two members:

```
MEMBER [Measures].[SegKey] as 
          [Segment].[skSegment].Currentmember.Member_Key
        ,NON_EMPTY_BEHAVIOR =[Measures].[Allocated Site Trans Date Revenue]

MEMBER [Measures].[TerrKey] as 
[Territory].[skTerritory].Currentmember.Member_Key
 ,NON_EMPTY_BEHAVIOR = [Measures].[Allocated Site Trans Date Revenue]
```

Then I reference them in my select:

```
Select Non Empty {[Measures].[Allocated Site Trans Date Revenue], [Measures].[SegKey],  
[Measures].[TerrKey]} on 0,
Non empty({[FYToCompleteMonthEnd], [LastFYToCompleteMonthEnd]}* {[CommCatABC]}* 
        {[Segment].[Customer Markets].[Customer Market].&[School], 
            [Segment].[Customer Markets].[Customer Market].&[Public Library]}) On 1
From Sales
```

Yet the returned values for those keys are 0.

What could be happening here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you try

```
Select 
     [Measures].[TerrKey] on 0,
     [Territory].[skTerritory].members on 1 
From Sales
```

If you change Member_Key by 'name' or 'key' ?

For the second non empty is strange your brackets '(', this if for functions and tuples. Can you try without?

Comment: Thanks for your reply!! OK, that query gives me the keys. So how would one translate back into the main query?

Comment: Thanks to icCube's suggestion I just added a new named set:

Set [SegTerrKeys] as
 nonempty ({[Segment].[skSegment].Children * [Territory].[skTerritory].Children})
And then crossjoined that my main query: {[SegTerrKeys]}

Thanks icCube!